# Как отследить нажатие Enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Доброго времени суток.

Я в JS знаком очень отдаленно, по этому какие-то банальные вещи мне кажутся совершенно страшными и невыполнимыми. Впрочем мне нужно решить одну проблему.

Решил сделать динамическую таблицу с подвязкой из БД. Нашел отличную штуку [PHP MySQL Inline Editing using jQuery Ajax](http://phppot.com/php/php-mysql-inline-editing-using-jquery-ajax/) Скачал, установил, все работает.

Что бы ячейка отредактировалась, мне нужно кликнуть в любом месте, но мне хочется пользоваться традиционным способом, просто нажать Enter и все. Здесь это не канает, при нажатии на Enter мы переходим на новую строку, даже если я уберу этот перенос строки в БД все равно запишется `<br>`.

За обновление данных в БД отвечает функция:

```
<script>
function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
    $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
    $.ajax({
        url: "saveedit.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
        success: function(data){
            $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
        }        
   });
}
</script>
```

Собственно вопрос, что и где нужно поменять в этом коде, что бы можно было просто нажать Enter и все записалось. Мне переносы строки не нужны.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    }
});  Если нужно нажатие клавиши ENTER

Answer (score 0):

Наверное что то типо того вам нужно:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) { 
e.preventDefault();

  if(e.which == 13) {
        function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
          $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");  
            $.ajax({
                url: "saveedit.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
                success: function(data){
                    $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
                }        
             });
        } 
  } 
});
```

Comment: Увы, это не помогло, перевод строки появляется. + ко всему данные теперь не записываются в БД

Comment: @OuFinx попробуйте так, обновил ответ, может поможет.